# How do I add app install banner in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to display a banner to give users a path into my app in app store.
How do I add an app install banner in flutter web? Is there any packages for implementation this banner?

[image: This image that I want to have]

Answer (score 0):

You can have like an in-app notification to show app banner in your app and when the user taps on the banner button/button itself, then it will redirect the user to the Playstore or Appstore.
Or if you want it in your app without any pop-up or anything, then you can place a Container and then place all the widgets there.
There may be several packages for this purpose on pub.dev

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as you can see in the picture of my question, I want to show an app install banner that refer to my app in the store whit its icon and its stars.

Comment: There might be multiple packages regarding that on pub.dev
Check them out!
Hope you find what you are looking for!

Comment: have you find anything?